# How does incremental crawl know what are the recent changed documents?

Tags: 2013, search

How does the incremental crawl know what are the recent changed documents? If by checking the SP modified date column, then what about external and non SharePoint sources and html web sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incremental process is dependent on the protocol handler being used. When detecting changes against Sharepoint sites, we use the "Sharepoint 3.0 (sts3) protocol handler".

We will first attempt to get changes from the last crawl.  We do this through MSDMN.exe process and hit a webservice called sitedatawebservice.

Read this article for detailes(this blog explain about Sitec changes).

[How to determine the number of changes an incremental crawl will process prior to initiating the crawl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2008/11/17/how-to-determine-the-number-of-changes-an-incremental-crawl-will-process-prior-to-initiating-the-crawl.aspx)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/230.full-and-incremental-crawls-in-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-search.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/18/sharepoint-2010-2013-search-incremental-crawl-vs-full-crawl.aspx

Comment: what about external websites?

Comment: check this one for more understanding http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-us/0aff725b-d7a6-4ad3-8dbc-d2c47bfab242/incremental-crawl-for-nonsharepoint-sites?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy